# Is there a way to use sort_by on a second criterion if the first is equal?

Tags: ruby, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort strings and numbers in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955646/sort-strings-and-numbers-in-ruby)

I have an array of *place* objects, each with a name (unique) and number (non-unique).  Is there a simple way to use sort_by to first sort by number and then (within each number) by name?

I know I can write a custom block for sort, but if this is possible, it'd be even easier!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean by "custom block" but it seems pretty simple to me:

```
places.sort_by { |place| [place.number, place.name] }
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for; thank you!  I didn't know you could pass it an array as well.

What I meant by "custom block" was array.sort {|x1, x2| x2 <=> x1}, essentially defining specifically how to sort items.  Your way's much better!