# Sort an Array of Strings by their Integer Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have an unsorted array from 1 to 10, as shown below...

```
a = ["3", "5", "8", "4", "1", "2", "9", "10", "7", "6"]
```

If I use the sort method on this array, it returns this...

```
a.sort = ["1", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

As you can see, the 10, appears before the 2, which is incorrect. How can I sort these numbers so that 10 appears correctly?

EDIT: Thank you all for your responses. I should explain my problem a little better. The array I need sorted is for an e-commerce price list. So the array appears as follows...

```
a = ["0-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40" etc.]
```

So the strings cannot be converted to integers. I should have put this when I wrote the question. I did not think that there would be much difference in the fix. My mistake, I apologise for making this assumption! How though can I sort this array? Thanks!

Comment: I think this question has already been answered:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955646/sort-strings-and-numbers-in-ruby/1964686#1964686

Comment: Just posted an answer to your updated question

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with updated description, since all the answers are base on the wrong description.

Comment: Since `#to_i` will interpret leading numeric characters in a string, the methods using `#to_i` will work for your example above.

Comment: I dont think it will.  '10-11'.to_i is 10.  try it

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'll throw another method out there since it's the shortest way I can think of

```
a.sort_by(&:to_i)
```

Comment: This is equivalent to bricker's answer, so his comment about the number of times `to_i` is called compared to Matt's solution applies here as well.

Comment: What is `&:`? That's a new syntax to me.

Comment: @nipponese That is a good question. Here is a good thread which explains it in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut.

Answer (score 10):

As your updated question states:

```
array.sort_by {|elt| ary = elt.split("-").map(&:to_i); ary[0] + ary[1]}
```

even geekier:

```
array.sort_by {|elt| ary = elt.split("-").map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you convert all strings to integers beforehand, it should work as expected:

```
a.map(&:to_i).sort
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter for such a small array, but your method would be faster than mine for large arrays, calling to_i only half as many times. +1

Comment: @bricker Matt's method also uses more memory as it creates a new array with `map` that your method doesn't.  (You could use the in-place map `map!`, but that might not always be a viable option in your code)

Answer (score 6):

```
a.sort { |a,b| a.to_i <=> b.to_i }
```

Comment: use Enumerable#sort_by instead

Comment: Why? The sort method works perfectly, I'd like to know why you recommend sort_by.

Comment: By definition xs.sort { |a, b| a.method <=> b.method } is totally equivalent to xs.sort_by(&:method). Why use sort when you have a shorter built-in exactly designed for this task? If that's not enough, there are also performance reasons, c&p from the docs: "As of Ruby 1.8, the method Enumerable#sort_by implements a built-in Schwartzian Transform, useful when key computation or comparison is expensive."

Comment: @tokland Thanks for the point about Schwartzian transforms occurring behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, that can be used in your example or others arrays like

```
a = ["teste", "test", "teste2", "tes3te", "10teste"]
```

is:

```
a.sort_by! {|s| s[/\d+/].to_i}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is that you have an array of strings and the sort that is being applied is string-based. To get the proper, numeric, sorting you have to convert the strings to numbers or just keep them as numbers in the first place. Is there a reason that your array is being populate with strings like this:

```
a = ["3", "5", "8", "4", "1", "2", "9", "10", "7", "6"]
```

Rather than numbers like this:

```
a = [3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 2, 9, 1, 7, 6]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The cheap way would be to zero fill on the left and make all numbers 2 digit.

Comment: Cheap & best way is to sort them as integers instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

For the special case (e-commerce price list) you mentioned

```
a = ["0-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40"]
```

let's add a few more values to this array (as it was mentioned as price list). so

```
a = ["0-10", "11-20", "120-150", "110-120", "21-30", "31-40"]
```

we can sort such an array using the following

```
a.sort.sort_by(&:length)
```