# Sort an Array of Strings by their Integer Values (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Products and in that model I have a column called "Size". How can I order sort my products by their size? (Something like 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11).

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully
[Here][1] It answers your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726968/sort-an-array-of-strings-by-their-integer-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to have the field as a string, you can do

```
Product.all.sort_by{|p| p.size.to_f}
```

However, if you can change the field from a string to a float you can do the more efficient..

```
Product.order(:size)
```